# Darle funcionalidad a un método de un objeto literal

Tags: javascript

Hola me piden que agregue la funcionalidad de venderAuto que recibe la patente y, en caso de encontrar al automóvil, le asigna el estado de vendido.

```js
   let autos = [{
       marca: 'Ford',
       modelo: 'Fiesta',
       precio: 150000,
       km: 200,
       color: 'Azul',
       cuotas: 12,
       anio: 2019,
       patente: 'APL123',
       vendido: false
   },
   {
       marca: 'Toyota',
       modelo: 'Corolla',
       precio: 100000,
       km: 0,
       color: 'Blanco',
       cuotas: 14,
       anio: 2019,
       patente: 'JJK116',
       vendido: false
   }];

   module.exports = autos;
```

Como punto de partida tengo este código, quisiera ver cuál es mi error en el método venderAuto:

```js
   let autos = require('./autos');

   let concesionaria = {
    autos: autos,

       buscarAuto: function(patente) {
           let autoEncontrado = this.autos.find(auto => auto.patente == patente);
           return autoEncontrado !== undefined ? autoEncontrado : null
       },

       venderAuto: function(patente) {
           let auto = this.autos.indexOf(this.buscarAuto(patente));
           if (auto === true) {
               autos[auto].vendido = true;
           }
       }
   }

   console.log(concesionaria.buscarAuto('APL123'));
   console.log(concesionaria.venderAuto('APL123')); // Devuelve undefined
```

Comment: En la segunda función, auto es un número. No tiene sentido compararlo con un `true`. Deberías verificar que el auto se encuentra en la lista mediante la comparación `auto >= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Algunas cosas.

- `venderAuto` va a imprimir `undefined` siempre que no tenga `return`,
- `indexOf` busca las coincidencias usando la iguadad estricta `===`, es decir que no va a funcionar con objetos, ejemplo `{} === {}` es `false`.

Yo creo que sería mejor trabajar con indices, y por consiguiente usar `findIndex` en lugar de `find`. En cualquier caso puedes hacer otro método para mostrar el auto en cuestión.

```js
let autos = [{
    marca: 'Ford',
    modelo: 'Fiesta',
    precio: 150000,
    km: 200,
    color: 'Azul',
    cuotas: 12,
    anio: 2019,
    patente: 'APL123',
    vendido: false
  },
  {
    marca: 'Toyota',
    modelo: 'Corolla',
    precio: 100000,
    km: 0,
    color: 'Blanco',
    cuotas: 14,
    anio: 2019,
    patente: 'JJK116',
    vendido: false
  }
];

let concesionaria = {
  autos: autos,

  mostrarAuto: function(patente) {
    let auto = this.buscarAuto(patente);
    if (auto !== -1) {
      console.log(autos[auto])
    }
  },

  buscarAuto: function(patente) {
    return this.autos.findIndex(auto => auto.patente == patente);
  },

  venderAuto: function(patente) {
    let auto = this.buscarAuto(patente);
    if (auto !== -1) {
      autos[auto].vendido = true;
    } else {
      console.log("No existe un auto con esa patente")
    }
  }
}


concesionaria.mostrarAuto('APL123'); // <-- previo a la modificación
concesionaria.venderAuto('APL123'); // <-- la modificación
concesionaria.mostrarAuto('APL123'); // <-- modificado
```